# EOFError: Ran out of input (CNN model)

Tags: python, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm following [a tutorial](https://www.ahmedbesbes.com/blog/acl-tear-detection-part-2) on how to build CNN's for MRI.

I'm attempting to train the model myself and I've got a "data" folder in the folder where the files are (downloaded from his [github](https://github.com/ahmedbesbes/mrnet)) but when I try to train the model I get an error.

I run this in a CMD: `python train.py -t acl -p sagittal --epochs=20 --prefix_name=one`

However it returns:

```
    (Pytorch) C:\Users\GlaDOS\mrnet>python train.py -t acl -p sagittal --epochs=20 --prefix_name=one
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 277, in <module>
    run(args)
  File "train.py", line 214, in run
    mrnet, train_loader, epoch, num_epochs, optimizer, writer, current_lr, log_every)
  File "train.py", line 34, in train_model
    for i, (image, label, weight) in enumerate(train_loader):
  File "C:\Users\GlaDOS\anaconda3\envs\Pytorch\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py", line 279, in __iter__
    return _MultiProcessingDataLoaderIter(self)
  File "C:\Users\GlaDOS\anaconda3\envs\Pytorch\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py", line 719, in __init__
    w.start()
  File "C:\Users\GlaDOS\anaconda3\envs\Pytorch\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 112, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "C:\Users\GlaDOS\anaconda3\envs\Pytorch\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 223, in _Popen
    return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Users\GlaDOS\anaconda3\envs\Pytorch\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 322, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Users\GlaDOS\anaconda3\envs\Pytorch\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 89, in __init__
    reduction.dump(process_obj, to_child)
  File "C:\Users\GlaDOS\anaconda3\envs\Pytorch\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 60, in dump
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'run.<locals>.<lambda>'

(Pytorch) C:\Users\GlaDOS\mrnet>Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\GlaDOS\anaconda3\envs\Pytorch\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 105, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd)
  File "C:\Users\GlaDOS\anaconda3\envs\Pytorch\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 115, in _main
    self = reduction.pickle.load(from_parent)
EOFError: Ran out of input
```

I'm sorta stranded on this unfortunately. Does anyone recognize what could be happening here? I'm assuming it's some setting on my end that doesn't allow the model to run as I haven't changed anything in his original code.

Comment: I read the github page, did you add 'models' and 'logs' folder in the directory?

Comment: Yes. Here's an image showing exactly how it's set up: https://prnt.sc/tisz5q

Comment: try changing lines 177 and 182 of `train.py` from `num_workers=11` to `num_workers=0` . I think it's to do with the Windows limit of Pickle loader.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change lines `177` and `182` of `train.py` from `num_workers=11` to `num_workers=0` . Windows has limit on the Pickle loader.

Answer (score 0):

set num_workers =0 in line 177 and 182
it should work fine

Comment: Why did you feel the need to add a duplicate answer to the accepted one?